# Equivariant morphisms to $G/H$ are locally trivial?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and $G$ is a complex algebraic group which acts on X. Fix also an algebraic subgroup $H \subset G$ and consider a $G$-equivariant morphism $f\colon X \rightarrow G/H$. Is it true that $f$ is locally trivial in standard analytic topology (or etale)?

Comment: Did you mean '$G$-invariant' instead of '$G$-equivariant'? Or is there some action of $G$ on $X$?

Comment: Thank you! I have edited my question -- I mean $G$-equivariant ($G$ acts on $X$).